# VBA User-defined functions in Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365, user-defined-functions

Some MS Office versions place restrictions on user-defined functions.
Specifically, [UDFs cannot write to the excel worksheet outside the cells that call the function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1).

My question: does this restriction apply in Office 365 as well?

Comment: There's no fundamental difference between Excel in Office 365 and the previous versions.

Comment: If there's something specific you want to achieve it might be useful to describe that - someone may have suggestions for an alternate approach.

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes". Limitation is in VBE, it doesn't matter which version you use. It applies to all excel versions. However as @TimWilliams mentioned, please describe your goal and someone may suggest some alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

You can change more than one cell if you use dynamic Spilling:

```
Public Function Stooges() As Variant
    Dim arr(1 To 3) As Variant
    
    arr(1) = "Larry"
    arr(2) = "Moe"
    arr(3) = "Curly"
    
    Stooges = arr
End Function
```

[image]

Note that in Excel 365, array-entry is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The same restriction applies to all Office versions and editions. There were no breaking changes so far, especially for Office 365 applications.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,

The answer is "No".
Excel 365 allows more flexibility.

The answer by @Gary'sStudent led me to look for "spilling" and "dynamic arrays".
These are featured that were added in Excel 365.  Here are the references:

[Spilling](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)

[Custom functions and dynamic arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-dynamic-arrays)

Thanks!

Comment: UDFs can't write directly to cells but they can return arrays and the array values will go in adjacent cells. Prior to Excel 365 such a function would need to be entered as an array formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.